# Dropdownlist Issue in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 tables:

```
table_section
-------------
section_id
section_name

table_class
-----------
class_id
class_name
section_id_f
```

I want to have 1 drop down list displaying both section_name and class_name as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: If you make an attempt at this and then ask a specific question on problems you encounter, you will get a better response.

Comment: You can embed an image right in the post.

Comment: I would create a list where it's section name followed by class name. Then data bind this list to the drop down. Finally use CSS to change the appearance of the even and odd rows.